Generating a mesh with fine elements around certain areas
I want to generate a mesh on the following domain that has finer mesh elements near the edges of the seven disks. How can I do so?
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

Domain[scale_, radius_] := RegionDifference[
   Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 0}, {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}*scale],
   RegionUnion[
    Disk[{0, 0}, radius*scale], 
    Disk[{1, 0}, radius*scale],
    Disk[{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, radius*scale], 
    Disk[{-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, radius*scale], 
    Disk[{-1, 0}, radius*scale], 
    Disk[{-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, radius*scale], 
    Disk[{1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, radius*scale]]];

ToElementMesh[Domain[1, 0.2], MaxCellMeasure -> .001]["Wireframe"]



Please look at the documentation for ToElementMesh, and find MeshRefinementFunction option.

Got it.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

Domain[scale_, radius_] := RegionDifference[
   Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 
       0}, {-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}}*scale],
   RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}*scale, radius], Disk[{1, 0} scale, radius],
     Disk[{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}*scale, radius], 
    Disk[{-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}*scale, radius], 
    Disk[{-1, 0}*scale, radius], 
    Disk[{-1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}*scale, radius], 
    Disk[{1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}*scale, radius]]];

refinementFunction[scale_, radius_] := 
  Function[{vertices, area}, 
   Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices]; 
    If[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 1.1*radius && 
      Sqrt[(x - scale)^2 + y^2] > 1.05*radius && 
      Sqrt[(x + scale)^2 + y^2] > 1.05*radius && 
      Sqrt[(x - 0.5*scale)^2 + (y - Sqrt[3]/2*scale)^2] > 
       1.05*radius && 
      Sqrt[(x - 0.5*scale)^2 + (y + Sqrt[3]/2*scale)^2] > 
       1.05*radius && 
      Sqrt[(x + 0.5*scale)^2 + (y - Sqrt[3]/2*scale)^2] > 
       1.05*radius && 
      Sqrt[(x + 0.5*scale)^2 + (y + Sqrt[3]/2*scale)^2] > 1.05*radius,
      area > 0.001*(scale)^2, area > 0.0000003*(scale)^2]]];

ToElementMesh[Domain[50*^-6, 12.5*^-6], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> .001*(50*^-6)^2, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   refinementFunction[50*^-6, 12.5*^-6]]["Wireframe"]


